# Profile on Meta.SO does not show upvotes on CW posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, community-wiki, reputation-history

On [the reputation tab of my profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone?tab=reputation), I can see upvotes on posts that are Community Wiki.  For example, on November 13th 2012, I received one upvote on a Community Wiki post:

[image: Community Wiki upvote on reputation tab of casperOne's profile on Stack Overflow]

However, after [putting all of my effort in creating a Stack Overflow-flavored version of Run-D.M.C.'s "Christmas in Hollis"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158642/140951), I don't see the upvotes on the post [in my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140951/jolly-old-saint-nicholas?tab=reputation), despite it (currently) having six votes:

[image: Community Wiki upvote on reputation tab of casperOne's profile on Meta Stack Overflow]

I'd expect that I can see upvotes on my CW posts on Meta just like I can on the main site.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to happen fairly inconsistently. At first I thought maybe it only happened with posts that were made community wiki in the original revision, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @TimStone Well, the original version of the post *is* CW, it's just that it inherited that from the question.

Comment: @TimStone: Yeah, I'm a bit baffled. I have *tons* of CW events in my history, just look at May 2... This also probably means it's not limited to Meta, it's just a random hiccup somewhere that applies to all sites.

Comment: Yeah, I meant it in the opposite sense that such posts would be hidden, but ChrisF's profile proves otherwise.

Comment: @TimStone Well, hopefully this will help you isolate the issue.

Comment: @animuson It's not limited to Meta, no, I don't see the [December 10th up vote](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3076078/timeline) for the CW answer in question in my [Stack Overflow profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366234/tim-stone?tab=reputation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug is different than described...the votes don't appear on any site *until a recalc*.

The vote recording code doesn't record a target for that vote (since reputation-wise, it doesn't matter).  However, as part of many things that happens on a recalc, the owners get fixed up and then the rep history items get created.

Starting with the next build, we'll record the votes with a target from the start...and the rep history items will follow.

Comment: Come on, Tim Stone should *totally* have been able to figure that out. *rolls eyes*