# Syntax highlighting in app differs from normal web view

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, syntax-highlighting

I've just noticed viewing a Python [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278515) (since modified: see [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27278515/2)) on Stack Overflow that the Android app shows `new` (incorrectly) highlighted as a keyword which differs from the normal render from the web page.

[image: Example]

While it should look more similar to:

[image]

Notice no highlighting for `new`.

Comment: The app also highlights all the special characters `:=[]().` etc, whereas the main site doesn't. I wonder if they use a completely different highlighter for the app.

Comment: @animuson and different colouring for literals etc... however, I was trying to not make it a stylistic question, more a "the language highlighter is not recognising the correct keywords for a language" kind of thing

Comment: @nicael oops - thanks for edit :)

Comment: Despite the age of this question, this still seems to be an "issue" (whether a bug or feature is up to you). I've just created an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729657/is-there-anyway-in-opencsv-to-mention-start-from-this-line-and-at-specific-line/34733698#34733698) which isn't prettified by either FF43 or Chrome47 at all. The Android app performs rather nicely, though.

Comment: @morido in your case, the issue was caused by "no suitable language detected based on the tag" (previously only [tag:opencsv]). I have fixed it by adding [tag:java] on the question, and your answer now has syntax highlighting. However, I acknowledged the issue.

Comment: @AndrewT. Cool, thanks. So there is generally a need to attribute a language tag to a specific question even if other tags (such as "opencsv* which happens to be a Java-only library) already unambiguously identify the language?

Comment: @morido yes, [it has to be specified on the tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). As an example, [opencsv doesn't have code language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info), whereas [Android has default code language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) (it's on the very bottom)

Comment: Related: [Should the Android app be adding syntax highlighting for code blocks without code tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196384/should-the-android-app-be-adding-syntax-highlighting-for-code-blocks-without-cod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

I'm not sure where that color scheme came from but it's been lingering around for almost three years.  Updating to match the iOS app and web.